# Response on Xml data is skipped when reaching special characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing, response

I'm not able to parse the xml response when i hit on a special characters why is it so? is there any solutions for it?

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Please read this, maybe it is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents